# How can i add/delete vpc in hosted zone in aws route53 using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-route53

I am using boto with Route 53 and i can create hosted zone with private zone and vpc,

```
zone = conn.create_hosted_zone('test_yyy.com', private_zone=True, vpc_id='vpc-0dba83fhd', vpc_region='us-east-1')
```

But i need to add/delete vpc's in created zone

Is there any possibility to doing through boto?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AssociateVPCWithHostedZone[1] Route 53 API call.  It looks like boto just recently[2] merged in the changes to support this.

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_AssociateVPCWithHostedZone.html
2. https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2886